# python function missing 2 required positional arguments: ln1, ln2

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

```
def di(l1,l2, ln1, ln2):  
   dlt = (l2-l1)
   dln = (ln2-ln1)    
   d = dlt * dln
return d

abc = newdf[['l1','l2','ln1','ln2']]
abc.columns
```

Function working without errors. But while working on dataframe, it showing error as

> di() missing 2 required positional arguments: ln1, ln2

```
newdf = newdf.withColumn('newcolnm',reduce(di, ( newdf[col] for col in abc.columns ) ))
```

Comment: reduce takes 2 parameters

Comment: where is your radial_distance() ?

Comment: @pygirl which 2 parameters reduce takes

Comment: It is hard to tell what your code is doing, since it is not a complete, reproducible example. However, the purpose of [``reduce``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is to apply a function of the form ``(T, T) -> T`` (exactly *2* arguments of the same type), which ``d1`` simply does not match. What do you intend a reduction by ``di`` to mean? What do you expect ``ln1`` and ``ln2`` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is correct but when calling the function you arent passing requited 4 arguments. your calling should be like funct(a, b, c, d)

if you don't want parameters compulsory define your function as

```
di (p1=None, p2=None, p3=None, p4=None)
```

with this you can omit unwanted parameters

Comment: newdf = newdf.withColumn('newcolnm',reduce(di, ( newdf[col] for col in abc.columns ) ))   ..... is it correct to call function ?